# Comobox Windows 10 MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to bind values to Combobox in a Windows 10 Universal App. I am using MVVM Light. I can bind all values properly except for Combo Box. The items are never shown. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
 <Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BigappleSP.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModels="using:BigappleSP.ViewModels"
x:Class="BigappleSP.Views.ContactusPage"
mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="{Binding ContactusViewModdel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <RelativePanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" MinWidth="320" 
            PlaceholderText="Name" InputScope="PersonalFullName"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            Text="{Binding ContactusViewModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Margin="10,10"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmail" MinWidth="320"
            PlaceholderText="Email"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.Below="txtName"
            Margin="10,10" 
            Text="{Binding ContactusViewModel.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
            InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" />

        <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" MinWidth="320"
            PlaceholderText="Phone Number"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.Below="txtEmail" Margin="10,10"
            InputScope="TelephoneNumber" 
            Text="{Binding ContactusViewModel.PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


        <ComboBox x:Name="lstOptions" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="35"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.Below="txtPhone" Margin="10,10"                      
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactusViewModel.AvailableOptions, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            PlaceholderText="How can we help you" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            DisplayMemberPath="Title">

        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtMessage" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="150"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.Below="lstOptions"
            InputScope="Text" Margin="10,10" 
            Text="{Binding ContactusViewModel.Message, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


    </RelativePanel>

</Grid>
```

View Model

```
public class ContactusViewModel : Template10.Mvvm.ViewModelBase
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }



    private ObservableCollection<Options> _options = new ObservableCollection<Models.Options>();

    public ObservableCollection<Options> Options
    {
        get
        {
            if (_options == null || _options.Count <= 0)
            {
                _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 1, Title = "Development" });
                _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 2, Title = "Training" });
                _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 3, Title = "Consulting" });

            }
            return _options;
        }
        set
        {
            _options = value;
        }
    }



    public string Message { get; set; }
    // constructor

    public ContactusViewModel()
    {

        _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 1, Title = "Development" });
        _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 2, Title = "Training" });
        _options.Add(new Options() { Id = 3, Title = "Consulting" });
       // Options = _options;

    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameter, mode, state);
    }

}
```

I am using Options as observable collection to bind to Combo Box.

Comment: Show some binding that is actually working, or your entire xaml if it is not too long.  Normally, you set the data context of the entire page to the view model, so you would normally use `ItemsSource="{Binding Options, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: Sure. I thought I copied the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `AvailableOptions` property on your view model, there is only `Options`.

You also need to have another property in the view model for the selected option, and bind it to the combo box's `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. There was a typo as well in the code which prevented the ViewModel to be fired properly. I will post the full working code below so it helps someone else.